# Components that do not consume from context still re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

How can I make sure that only the right components get re-rendered?

I have this example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-hr2s6?file=/src/index.js).

I want to control the state within that context from my top level component, but still I want to make sure that the `SomeOtherComponent` component doesn't get re-rendered.

```
// index.js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const memo = useMemo(
    () => ({
      currentCount: count,
      setCurrentCount: setCount
    }),
    [count]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CountDisplayContext.Provider value={memo}>
        <Content />
      </CountDisplayContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// CountDisplay.js
export const CountDisplayContext = createContext({
  currentCount: 0,
  setCurrentCount: () => {}
});

export default () => {
  const { currentCount, setCurrentCount } = useContext(CountDisplayContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {currentCount}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentCount(currentCount + 1)}>
        Increment!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
// Content.js
export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Display component</h1>
      <CountDisplay />
      <hr />
      <SomeOtherComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
// SomeOtherComponent.js
export default () => {
  console.log("I don't want this to be re-rendered all the time!");
  return <div>Hello</div>;
};
```

Comment: To boil it down event more simply, you can remove the context and pass the state through as props and see the same behavior.  I did that on [a fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-qrc7f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) of your sandbox.

Comment: My realworld example of course isn't as simple as this. But I found out later that my main problem was to do with HOCs and `Form.create()` from AntDesign specifically. I'm solving this by upgrading ant from v3 to v4 and use the `useForm` hook  instead of the `Form.create` HOC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can opt-in into this optimisation by wrapping your component with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

```
// SomeOtherComponent.js
export default React.memo(() => {
  console.log("I don't want this to be re-rendered all the time!");
  return <div>Hello</div>;
});
```

This will make it so `SomeOtherComponent` only re-renders if any props it receives differs from previous render.

Also, you might find [this writing](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/optimize-react-re-renders) useful. It talks about this deeper.